# On click of recommendation of keyboard words in edit text how to close the keyboard

Tags: android

**What I have currently**

- I am using a editText
- On clicking of editttext keyboard pops up
- Now I use keyboard to type

**What I am trying to achieve:**

- On click of search icon on keyboard I want to close the keyboard
- On click of recommendation shown on keyboard words  for edit text how to close the
  keyboard

**What I am able to achieve:** `On click of search icon on keyboard I want to close the keyboard`

```
getSearchView().setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    hidekeyBoard(context,v);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

**What I am not able to achieve**: `On click of recommendation shown on keyboard words  for edit text how to close the keyboard`

Comment: You can use `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` rather than editText

Answer (score 0):

```
 getSearchView().setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean actionSearchDone = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                //TODO do search action of your logic
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) {
                    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                actionSearchDone = true;
            }
            return actionSearchDone;
        }
    });
```